# Failed to create lock when creating conda environment

Tags: anaconda

I am trying to create a conda environment and I keep getting warnings about failures to create locks. Why is this happening and how can this be fixed?

```
Fetching packages ...
intelpython2_c 100% |################################| Time: 0:00:00   2.00 MB/s
Extracting packages ...
[      COMPLETE      ]|###################################################| 100%
Linking packages ...
WARNING conda.lock:touch(53): Failed to create lock, do not run conda in parallel processes [errno 13]
WARNING conda.lock:touch(53): Failed to create lock, do not run conda in parallel processes [errno 13]
WARNING conda.lock:touch(53): Failed to create lock, do not run conda in parallel processes [errno 13]
WARNING conda.lock:touch(53): Failed to create lock, do not run conda in parallel processes [errno 13]
WARNING conda.lock:touch(53): Failed to create lock, do not run conda in parallel processes [errno 13]
WARNING conda.lock:touch(53): Failed to create lock, do not run conda in parallel processes [errno 13]
WARNING conda.lock:touch(53): Fail
```